# How to share the same folder in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, file-sharing, shared-folders

In my windows 10, I have shareMe folder which is shared through my local network.

Now I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed to the same pc with dual boot option and I can see this shareMe in my files.

Is there anyway that I can share this same folder in Ubuntu too so that my network can see this same folder when I'm in ubuntu? I want this to achieve without affecting to the current sharing ability of the folder in windows.

Can I do it like that???

When I use Samba server

```
  sudo smbpasswd -a Ontash-User
  sudo: unable to resolve host leno-ubuntu
  New SMB password:
  Retype new SMB password:
  Failed to add entry for user Ontash-User.
```

Comment: Is that share-folder in the windows partition or in an independent one?

Comment: @m-becerra: It is in windows partition

Comment: Can you not just R-click, properties, local network share, check box local network share?

Comment: Very likely you can see the whole disk, not just the `shareMe`. So you can use Samba to share what ever folder you like from that disk.

Comment: If I install windows network sharing service to ubuntu, will that solve it???? And hope my windows files or files systems wont affect at all.

Comment: Samba is the way to go...  https://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/

Comment: The error is given by sudo, not by smbpasswd. Is the host 'leno-ubuntu' present in your /etc/hosts?

Comment: @willemk I used your link and everything is setup now. I had to create that Ontash-User in Ubuntu.  Now windows people can see my folder but they say they can'l go into it with Ontash-User credential

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cant go into it". What is the owner:group of your folder? What access do you want Ontash-User to have?